# Help understanding these 2 sentences

Tags: grammar, parsing

I have trouble understanding these 2 sentences below... 
Note: There is no further context provided.

> 1. 発車{はっしゃ}のベルが鳴{な}っているので飛{と}び乗{の}ったら、反対方向{はんたいほうこう}の電車{でんしゃ}だった

**My attempt:** Because the departure bell is ringing, if you hop (to the train), you will get into the opposite direction.

*The sentence doesn't make sense to me... :(*

> 2. 就職{しゅうしょく}試験{しけん}の結果{けっか}の連絡{れんらく}だと思って急いで電話に出{で}たら、間{ま}違{ちが}い電話{でんわ}だった

**My attempt:** If you are thinking about the notification result of the employment examination while make a phone call in a hurry, you will end up with calling a wrong number.

I'm not sure if I understand 急いで電話に出{で}たら correctly.
Since isn't *make a phone call* "電話をかける"?  But it would be strange to end up with a wrong number if you were receiving a phone call...

Comment: 電話に出る _to answer the phone;_ the phone is ringing, you think it's the phone call you're waiting for (so you hurry to answer), but it isn't. `But it would be strange to end up with a wrong number if you were receiving a phone call...` What's strange with that? People call wrong numbers all the time.

Comment: @oals yes you are right, it does make sense to receive a wrong phone call... My apologies, it seems my brain was not working correctly too much hard work trying to figure out the sentence :( ... And thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: That makes two of us then. I couldn't at first figure out the first one myself either, but then it suddenly started to make sense. (I only had half an answer when I wrote the comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For both sentences, you can translate the 「〜たら、……だった」 as *'it turned out to be ...'*

Also, both of the 〜たら have the meaning 'when', not 'if'.

> 発車のベルが鳴っているので飛び乗ったら、反対方向の電車だった

- 発車のベル 'the bell announcing a departing train'
- 飛び乗る 'to hop onto (the train)'
- There's a missing subject. I'm translating it as 'I' barring further context. The ['generic you'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you) as you translated the sentences with is incorrect because it's specifying a one-off event.

> *'I hopped onto the train because the departure bell was ringing, and it turned out to be the wrong train (going into the opposite direction).'*

---

> 2. 就職試験の結果の連絡だと思って急いで電話に出たら、間違い電話だった

- 就職試験の結果の連絡 'a phone call announcing the results of ...'
- 電話に出る 'to answer the phone'
- Another missing subject. Translated as 'I' again.
- 間違い電話 'it turned out to be the wrong number' (someone called your number mistakenly)

> *'I thought someone was phoning the results for the 就職試験 and hurried to the ringing phone, but it turns out it was a wrong number.'*